# Set Default Value in HTML / Blazor Select (Dropdown) Foreach

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu, blazor, default-value

I want to set a default Value from the foreach-loop in a Select List in HTML.

Thanks for your effort.

```
<select class="form-control" style="width: 160px" id="id">
@foreach (var option in Function())
{
    <option> @option </option>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to choose which value is selected and also get the updated value automatically, then you can use two-way binding:

```
<select @bind="BindString">
    @foreach (var item in ValuesFromFunction)
    {
        <option>@item</option>
    }
</select>
<br/>
<div>The selected value is: <b>@BindString</b></div>

@code {
    string BindString { get; set; } = "Three";
    List<string> ValuesFromFunction = new() { "One", "Two", "Three" };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<option value="value" selected>Option Name</option>
```

Comment: I dont want to get a new value, but i want to get a specific value from the foreach list.

Comment: you have to use this line only for an option which you want to select by default. Just put on @if(condition){ my line } else{ your line }.

Comment: You can definitely use a condition in your `foreach` as Jay suggested, but I think maybe you are looking for 2-way binding?  Let me know if my answer is what you meant.